# Incluso usando BigDecimal tengo problemas con el redondeo

Tags: java, bigdecimal, redondeo, double

¿Por qué si uso `BigDecimal` en este caso, no obtengo el resultado esperado?

```
double value1 = 5.68;
double value2 = 2.45;
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(value1 + value2));
```

## SALIDA:

```
8.129999999999999
```

## ESPERADO:

```
8.13
```

Comment: Si notas, primero sumas los double y luego lo conviertes a Bigdecimal

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas haciendo la suma de los `double` no de los `BigDecimal`

Te recomiendo esto en su lugar

```
double value1 = 5.68;
double value2 = 2.45;
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(value1).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(value2)));
```

De esta forma cada número es convertido primero en un `BigDecimal` antes de realizar la suma.

Como el operador `+` no funciona con `BigDecimal` se debe usar el método `.add()` en su lugar

Comment: Aunque esto funcione, explicar exactamente por qué me parece bastante más difícil que usar `String`: `BigDecimal.valueOf("5.68").add(BigDecimal.valueOf("2.45"))`.

Answer (score 5):

Cuando uses `BigDecimal`, conviene usar siempre los constructores y métodos que **no** usen el tipo `double`, ya que, como supongo ya sabes, el tipo `double` no tiene representaciones exactas para muchos números que tienen representación exacta en base 10.

Para tu ejemplo, podrías usar:

```
/* Usa valueOf(long valorSinEscalar, int escala) */
long value1 = 568;
long value2 = 245;
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(value1 + value2, 2));
```

o tal vez:

```
/* Usa el constructor BigDecimal(long valorSinEscalar, int escala) */
BigDecimal value1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(568, 2);
BigDecimal value2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(245, 2);
System.out.println(value1.add(value2));
```

o este otro:

```
/* Usa el constructor BigDecimal(String valor) */
BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("5.68");
BigDecimal value2 = new BigDecimal("2.45");
System.out.println(value1.add(value2));
```

Nótese que hay una versión de estos constructores con un parámetro adicional `MathContext`, que permite seleccionar el modo de redondeo.

Answer (score 1):

Puesto que la pregunta es sobre redondeo utilizando `BigDecimal`, solo debes usar el método [`BigDecimal#setScale(int, RoundingMode)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-):

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(value1 + value2).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
```

El resultado será:

```
8.13
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo de esto corriendo en [ideone](http://ideone.com/a9Iddv).

Obviamente, no significa que esta es la forma de proceder con las operaciones decimales. Lo mejor sería seguir el ejemplo brindado en [la respuesta de @ninjalj](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/1163/227), donde si vas a utilizar números decimales, inicialices `BigDecimal` utilizando cadenas en lugar de `double`:

```
/* Usa el constructor BigDecimal(String valor) */
BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("5.68");
BigDecimal value2 = new BigDecimal("2.45");
System.out.println(value1.add(value2));
```

De todas maneras, si las operaciones de arriba deben tener un número fijo de decimales, utiliza `setScale`.