# ¿Por qué tengo problemas con los valores decimales utilizando BigDecimal?

Tags: java, matemáticas, bigdecimal, coma-flotante

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(3.2);
System.out.println(num);
```

Esperado:

```
3.2
```

Salida.

```
3.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

Por lo tanto.

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(3.2);
BigDecimal num1 = new BigDecimal(2);
System.out.println(num.add(num1));
```

Esperado:

```
5.2
```

Salida.

```
5.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

No entiendo como se deben realizar cálculos con operaciones básicas en Java, no se si existe otra librería u otra forma de realizar esto.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz no es un duplicado exacto.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz ahora que leo mejor la pregunta que marcas como duplicado, el problema de `@JordiCadilla` era sobre el redondeo, y nadie en sus respuestas apunta a eso.

Comment: Al @CarlosMuñoz verdadero. alguien esta usando tu cuenta por ti, jaja

Comment: Cierto, ya retiré el voto de cierre, y la respuesta de @LuiggiMendoza es la correcta.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz agregué una respuesta adicional sobre la pregunta que colocaste como duplicado, apuntando al tema del redondeo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BigDecimal` es la clase que ofrece el JDK de Java para trabajar con números decimales de manera más exacta. El problema que tienes surge porque estás inicializando tus instancias de `BigDecimal` utilizando `double`, y este último sufre del problema clásico de operaciones de punto flotante. Este problema se explica con más detalle [en esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/227).

En Java, para que puedas utilizar el potencial de `BigDecimal` al utilizar números decimales, debes utilizar el constructor que recibe una cadena de texto:

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal("3.2");
```

En caso que estés inicializando una variable `BigDecimal` con un `double` porque no tienes otra salida p.e. cuando utilizas Apache POI y obtienes el valor numérico de una celda, entonces lo que **debes** hacer es redondear el valor de tu número a un número fijo de decimales:

```
double d = 3.2;
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Cuando utilizas `int` (entero) o `long` (entero largo), no hay ningún problema al inicializar tu variable:

```
BigDecimal num2 = new BigDecimal(2);
```

Relacionados:

- [Incluso usando BigDecimal tengo problemas con el redondeo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1132/227)