# BigDecimal no me retorna el valor esperado

Tags: java, poo, junit, bigdecimal

Actualmente estoy tabajando con `BigDecimal` para realizar operaciones básicas como sumar o restar, el problema es que no me retorna el valor que espero cuando utilizo valores númericos al crear el objeto de `BigDecimal`:

[image: main method]

Pero como resultado obtengo:

[image: result BigDecimal]

Dentro de mi clase `Cuenta` el costructor lo tengo así:

```
public Cuenta(String persona, BigDecimal saldo) {
        this.persona = persona;
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }
```

y el método `credito`:

```
 public void credito(BigDecimal monto){
    BigDecimal nuevosaldo = this.saldo.add(monto);
    this.saldo = nuevosaldo;
    }
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/1163/14311

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ajustar la precisión decimal de tu objeto `BigDecimal` . Simplemente prueba `monto.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);`

Tambien puedes inicializarlo así:

```
new BigDecimal("1000.23")
```

Fuente -> https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/four-common-pitfalls-of-the-bigdecimal-class-and-how-to-avoid-them